# Using Child's events

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a custom component (TScrollBox) that when dropped on a form, it will add a label inside the ScrollBox.  How can I disable the ScrollBox's events (onClick, OnMouseDown, ect..) and instead enable the events for the child (Tlabel)

```
unit MyScrollBox;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyScrollComponent = class(TScrollBox)
  private
    FLabel : TLabel;
    procedure SetLabelText(AText : string);
    function GetLabelText : string;
  protected
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  published       
    property LabelText : string read GetLabelText write SetLabelText;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMyScrollComponent]);
end;

constructor TMyScrollComponent.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FLabel := TLabel.Create(self);
  FLabel.Parent := self;
  FLabel.Caption := 'Hello From Scrollbox!';
end;

procedure TMyScrollComponent.SetLabelText(AText : string);
begin
  FLabel.Caption := AText;
end;

function TMyScrollComponent.GetLabelText : string;
begin
  result := FLabel.Caption;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Isn't this question a direct result of your design choice to derive from scroll box? Why not have a control that provides it's own scrolling capabilities?

Comment: Are you trying to change the behavior of the parent events, or implement new events of your own? Simply publishing a property of type `string` has nothing to do with events. Please clarify.

Comment: @vector neither. This code will create 1 component this component when dropped onto a form during design time it will drop a scrollbox and a label inside the scrollbox. I want To be able to use the on mouse down event for the label  currently it just gives option to use on mouse down event for the component (scrollbox)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That would also work, but i could not figure out how to do that, so instead i have a scroll box that host my custom component, Thus brings me to this question on how to access the events of the component inside the scrollbox

Comment: Well, I think you'll continue having such troubles until you implement scrolling properly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have asked with no answers or help.  So I Thought i would try a different approach.  But also this case would be good to know for down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The published events in `TScrollBox` cannot be suppressed in derived classes. So, treating your question literally, there is no way to achieve what you ask.

What you could do is derive from `TScrollingWinControl`. This is the ancestor to `TScrollBox`. It doesn't publish the events that you want to associate with the control contained in your scroll box.

Then you can surface events in your custom control that are connected to the control contained in your custom control.

Judging from your recent questions I cannot help in thinking that your approach is wrong. I feel that you should have a custom control that has built in scrolling capability.

Comment: Any advantages of not doing this and using built in scrolling?

Comment: Any advantages of not doing what? I'm not certain which option you mean.

Comment: This way vs the way u suggest.  aka using the TSCrollingWinControl vs having built in scrolling.

Comment: Just as a side note, I am not saying your wrong, Cause i have got that to work now, and i noticed its less typeing,to get to the events. and code is simpler to read.. but maybe there are other things i am missing that you where talking about.

Comment: I think it's cleaner to have just one control. That's all. You can surely make it work with multiple controls. It just feels dirty. Of course I don't know what your real control is. I have a feeling that it's a charting type control. Or an image viewing control.

Comment: It's a map and just wanted to have scroll bars incase it was a huge map. Before I just noted it must be placed inside a scroll box. But think it's better if there is no requirements. Cheers and thanks

Comment: I really believe that a control with in built scrolling will be better in the long run. May involve a learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

The event handlers for `TControls` are declared as `protected` and `dynamic`. Redeclare them using the `override` directive in your derived class - see [**TScrollBox Members Protected Methods**](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/_!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_Forms_TScrollBox_14_Protected_Methods.html);
 [**To override MouseDown, add the MouseDown method to the TDBCalendar class**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Responding_to_Mouse-down_Messages) and many other pages.

**But: If you want to implement your own *new* *events* you'd have to do something like this:**

```
   ...

    private

    fNewEvent:TNotifyEvent;

    procedure setNewEvent(notify:TNotifyEvent);
    function  getNewEvent:TNotifyEvent;

    procedure DoOnNewEvent;


    ....

    published 

    property OnNewEvent:TNotifyEvent read getNewEvent write setNewEvent;
```

i.e. - You need to implement a property of a **method type**, like `TNotifyEvent` which is built into Delphi. You can also create your own if you need to. If you want to see your event in the IDE like other Delphi components' events, you must declare it as `published`.

Then: In your new component implementation section do something like this:

```
procedure TMyclass.DoOnNewEvent;
begin

  if assigned (fNewEvent) then
   begin
   ....doStuff... 
      fNewEvent(self);
   end;

end;
```

You call `DoOnNewEvent` when the event that you want to control 'happens' in your code, so that the function assigned to `fNewEvent` will get called at that point in your code. (This is commonly known as a `callback` - when something "happens" in module A it *calls back* into module B letting it know that it happened, etc.)

If you want to define new GUI behavior, you have to examine the controls you're interested in and understand how to capture their actual "physical" events - i.e. when did the scrollbar scroll, when was the mouse clicked, and when that happens you call your `DoOnNewEvent` method. (This generally involves inspecting Windows messages coming into your application, "message cracking",etc - these messages inform your application of what's happening in "the outside world".)

In your consumer class, for example your main form where you're putting your scroll box, once you successfully publish your new event, you will see your event in the IDE on your new component, and you assign it and define the behavior you want for it in your consumer class, just like any other event in the IDE.

Take a look at the VCL source code for a simple component to get a better idea of what it looks like.

**But:** That's only if you really need your own **new** published events because overriding the parent's events is not sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Glenn is asking about events rather than virtual methods

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - with all due respect, I don't know what you mean. Events are just callbacks and they're declared as virtual methods. From the link I cited: `procedure MouseDown(Button: TButton, Shift: TShiftState, X: Integer, Y: Integer);override;` Maybe I don't understand the question at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - is the OP trying to ask how to implement **new** events? From your comment on the question I gather that's what you understood. If so this question needs to be closed/edited - it is **very** unclear.

Comment: No. That's a method. An event is a property.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I understand it's a property - which is mapped to a method - when you get down to it, it's a function pointer, that's all: _A MouseDown method is a protected method for a control's OnMouseDown event. The control itself calls MouseDown in response to a Windows mouse-down message. When you override the inherited MouseDown method, you can include code that provides other responses in addition to calling the OnMouseDown event._

Comment: Sorry if this was confusing. But issue is the custom scroll box is creating a tlabel inside it. But I can't access the On Mouse Down event of the label cause the label is a child of the custom component. So when I click on the label it is actually doing onclick on the custom component (tscrollbox)

Comment: @GlenMorse - you have it working and accepted David's answer and that's fine. But you can override `MouseDown` in `TScrollbox` and do what you want with the label that way, as explained.